# JTextArea - clear text and return caret to starting area

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, keylistener

I have a small but annoying problem. I am using a JTextArea to capture input with a KeyListener - it just captured input after the return button is pressed. The problem is that when I clear the text the caret stays on the second line which is irritating.

Here is the code:

```
@SuppressWarnings ("serial")
public class ProgramEditor extends JTextArea implements KeyListener {

    //FIELDS
    String command = "";

    //CONSTRUCTOR
    public ProgramEditor() {
        super();
        this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        this.setLineWrap(true);

        addKeyListener(this);

        this.requestFocus();
     }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
         int i = e.getExtendedKeyCode();
         if (i == 10){
            command = this.getText();
            this.setText(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because I am taking longer than one line input.

Comment: `this.requestFocus(true);`  I'm pretty sure that has been deprecated, and if so, your compiler will issue warnings.  Don't ignore compiler warnings, ***fix them!***  As an aside, some of the above (poorly formatted) code is unnecessary, and most of the rest is bad design or just plain bad coding.  If you got that example from a site, never visit that site again. It is teaching you atrocious habits.

Comment: Perhaps you could show me how it should be done? That might be more useful than just rubbishing my work?

Comment: 1) Use `DocumentListener` rather than `KeyListener`. 2) It would be better to have a factory method to make such text areas, than by extending the component. 3) `this.setFocusable(true);` is pointless, given that is the default. 4) The call to `requestFocus()` will fail. (If it is focused in your app., it is because it is the first focusable component). 5) `requestFocus(true);` should be `requestInWindowFocus(true);`. 6) `if (i == 10){` Don't use magic numbers, there are constants defined for the keys. 7) `setText(null);` has already been covered in an answer. -- But this is not code review.

Comment: I presume you are trying to be helpful so ... thanks I guess...

Comment: I presume you are trying to sound grateful, while actually making a sideways criticism.  So to hell with you, you were the one that wanted tips and those 7 tips came to within 2 characters of the limit for comments.

Comment: Yeah sorry - I guess I was being a little touchy there :) Thanks. By the way for anyone interested I found the answer and it is simply this.consume(); this.setText("");

Comment: -1, `By the way for anyone interested I found the answer and it is simply this.consume();` - Swing was designed to be used with Key Bindings. Yes, this approach will work but that is NOT the way Swing was designed to be used. You should simple create a simple Action and bind the Action to the Enter key. This is a really simple implementation of Key Bindings. Why not learn to do it now so you understand the concept when you have a more complicated problem to solve.

Comment: Just for the record: `requestFocus()` is "discouraged", not quite deprecated and `requestFocus(true)` is ONLY shown as an option in Netbeans 7.4 if I ask for deprecated members to be included in code completion, so I imagine that's equivalent to "deprecated". (Even so, Javadoc does NOT say "deprecated.") It's hard to know what's deprecated and often harder to know why, although Javadoc says "platform dependence" is why in this case. Consider also that Netbeans GUIbuilder allows the selection of options that are deprecated (e.g., `setNextFocusableComponent`).

Answer (score 1):

Swing using Key Bindings to handle events. For a JTextArea the Enter key is handled by a key bindings which inserts a newline string into the text area. So this code is executing AFTER your keyPressed code.

The proper solution is to replace the default Action for the Enter key with a custom Action of your own. Read the section from Swing tutorial on [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more information and examples.

The question is why are you using a JTextArea in the user can never enter a newline character? A easier solution would be to just use a JTextField. Then you can add an ActionListener to the text field to handle the Enter key.

Finally, the worst solution would be to try handling the keyReleased() method. Then the default Action for the enter key of the text area should have been executed.

Comment: Im using the jText area with text wrap because the length of the command can be very long and wont fit on one line on many occasions, and the user needs to be able to look back over the text. It is essentially a macro programmer for a little animator program I designed... otherwise I would have used a textfield --- would't I?

Comment: I mean I thought about using a JButton instead of the return key to get the entered text - but then if someone where ever to press the return button it would then be impossible to ever clear the textArea again - which just seems crazy. I'll read the section on bindings and see if I can find a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `setCaretPosition(int)` method in JTextArea, specifically, make `keyPressed` into

```
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int i = e.getExtendedKeyCode();
if (i == 10){
    command = this.getText();
    this.setText(""); //I'd use "" over null; it just seems more proper to keep a string even if there's no difference
    this.setCaretPosition(0);
}
}
```

Check this out: [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setCaretPosition(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setCaretPosition%28int%29)

Comment: That doesnt work I dont know why... but it was the first thing I tried. I tried this.setCaratPosition(1) too --- that put the carat to the correct position but it throws a runtime exception...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
this.setCaretPosition(0);
```